# List Generics - implicit casting

Tags: .net, generics, casting, implicit-conversion

I'm targeting .NET 3.5.  Let's say I have a class, Bob, which is an abstract base class for SubBob.

I can declare this:

```
Bob b = new SubBob();
```

But I can't do this:

```
 // compliation error - can't convert
BindingList<Bob> myList = new BindingList<SubBob>();
```

My guess is that BindingList doesn't want you to do this because it has to know that the type that's on the right hand side has the same memory layout as the left hand side. SubBob may have a larger size than a Bob.

Is there a way I can do the implicit conversion, or is a cast required?

Comment: are you using visual studio 2010?

Comment: @Daniel - What does it matter what version of VS he is using?  He already said he is going to target 3.5 which means C# 3.0 is the version he will be using.

Comment: No, the 4.0 compiler will be used.

Comment: Next line: `myList.Add(new SomethingOtherThanASubBobButThatAlsoDerivesFromBob())`. Do you see what the issue is yet, for this list that's only expecting to contain `SubBob` instances?

Comment: @Daniel White, each project is specified with the Target Framework. VS2010 lets you target any existing framework as of 4.0

Comment: @Stealth - Visual Studio 2008 also allowed you to do this.

Comment: Size is irrelevant here; as far as `BindingList<T>` is concerned, both `Bob` and `SubBob` are the same size - specifically, a reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### The Short Answer

By instantiating `BindingList<SubBob>` you confine it to work with `SubBob` and *more specific* types (e.g. `SubSubBob`).

If you want `Bob` to fit there as well, declare `myList` as a list of **the least specific type you want to support**:

```
BindingList<Bob> myList = new BindingList<Bob>();
```

(or, more conveniently,)

```
var myList = new BindingList<Bob>();
```

#### Explanation

It is not about memory (`BindingList` would only hold a reference to the object, and all references are of the same size), rather it is about logical inconsistency you would introduce.

If such code was possible, you would be able to **arbitrarily break type restrictions**:

```
BindingList<Animal> myList = new BindingList<Cat>(); 
myList.Add(new Dog()); // bang!
```

`myList` is a list of `Cat`s, how would you expect it to handle a `Dog`?

Compiler wouldn't know there is a problem and would happily compile your code. What should happen when this code runs? An exception? But generics were introduced exactly to solve type safety problem.

#### A Side-Note on Co- and Contravariance

It's correct that in .NET 4.0, [generic covariance and contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx) were added for delegates and interfaces (**not for classes**). For example, [`IEnumerable<out T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspxhttp://) is covariant that means you can assign it to variable of any type *less derived* than `T`:

```
IEnumerable<Cat> cats = new List<Cat> { new Cat("Hudson"), new Cat("Crookshanks") };
IEnumerable<Animal> animals = cats; // sequence of cats is sequence of animals
```

But this is only possible because `IEnumerable<out T>` guarantees it **only returns** `T` (keyword `out`) and **never accepts** it. If it accepted `T` as parameter, it would open the door to the problem described above. For this reason, `ICollection` is *not* covariant.

In a similar fashion, some interfaces guarantee they **only accept** `T` (keyword `in`) and **never return** it. Such interfaces are called *contravariant* and allow assignment to a variable with *more specific* `T`:

```
IComparer<Animal> animalComparer = // ...
IComparer<Dog> dogComparer = animalComparer; // comparer of animals is comparer of dogs
```

Answer (score 1):

**Regarding your case specifically**:
You are dealing with **contravariance** here and a class can only support **covariance OR contravariance**. `IEnumerable<T>` supports covariance.

Its signature is `IEnumerable<out T>`, so it supports inherited classes of the class in `T`.

**In general**:
Unfortunately this is not available in .NET 3.5.

It was introduced in .NET 4 as [Covariance and Contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx).

There is [a FAQ on the subject at MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx). Here's an excerpt:

```
// Assignment compatibility. 
string str = "test";
// An object of a more derived type is assigned to an object of a less derived type. 
object obj = str;

// Covariance. 
IEnumerable<string> strings = new List<string>();

// Contravariance.           
// Assume that I have this method: 
// static void SetObject(object o) { } 
Action<object> actObject = SetObject;
```

Comment: Even then, for the specific example of a `List<T>`, it doesn't help.

Comment: Damien is correct. When I target .NET 4, covariance would kick in if the variable was of type IEnumerable. This doesn't work with BindingList<T> for some reason, even though BindingList<T> is a deriviative of IEnumerable<T> and IList<T>

Comment: -1 because covariance and contravariance have little to do with the problem described. `BindingList<T>` is a class, not an interface, and underlying `IBindingList` is not generic at all. `ICollection<T>` does not support type variancy, and `IEnumerable<T>` is out of question because we want to `Add` items.. The real problem is *there's no actual need* to declare `myList` as `BindingList<SubBob>` because the author seems to *intend* it to act like `BindingList<Bob>`.

Comment: @Stealth: you can use `IEnumerable` covariance but in only extends on enumeration. `IList` is neither co- nor contravariant.

Comment: @Dan I'm pretty sure ´BindingList<T>´ inherits ´IEnumerable<T>´ and therefor actually has the covariance described above. The ´Add´ method points to the same ´T´ and takes the covariance in consideration.

Comment: @Seb: `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant, not `IList<T>`, `ICollection<T>`, `IBindingList` or `BindingList` itself (which is a class and cannot be covariant by definition). Its `Add` method is inherited from `Collection<T>` which implements `IList<T>.Add` and `ICollection<T>.Add`. Neither of those interfaces is covariant. As to why, please see explanation in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898583/list-generics-implicit-casting/6898680#6898680).

Comment: I haven't reflected down and seen where .Add stems from and I don't really see anything in the question about .Add. But if it's all about the .Add, then that's of course correct.

Comment: @Seb: You're right, I thought the question had to do with `Add` for some odd reason. But my point is, there would be no use in `BindingList` if we only could use `GetEnumerator`, right? I assumed OP wanted to at least be able to fill the list somehow, and for some reason he wants to do this using `myList` variable. (And this is where `IEnumerable<out T>` being covariant wouldn't help him in the slightest.)

Comment: @Dan We all wonder what the reasons is for most of the questions here :P

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way I can do the implicit conversion, or is a cast
>   required?

The following should let any class that inherits Bob to be added to the list as a Bob.

```
BindingList<Bob> myList = new BindingList<Bob>();
```

What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to store a BindingList<T> where T is a base class type used for subclasses. My Data Access layer currently returns the explicity list type, i.e. BindingList<SubBob>(), but the GUI doesn't care about the subtype in this case.

Comment: "The fact you are even asking this kind of question tells me your new to C#."
What's your point (this is the correct use of 'your')? I'm asking a question because I want assistance and am looking for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code doesn't work is that generics don't inherit the hierarchy of their arguments: `BindingList<SubBob>` does not derive from `BindingList<Bob>`.  It has nothing to do with their memory layouts.

A `BindingList<Bob>` can already contain `SubBob` objects (and anything else deriving from `Bob`), so there might not actually be a need for a `BindingList<SubBob>`.  If for some reason there *is* a reason you need both, your only "easy" option may be to use the non-generic `IBindingList` interface.

.NET 4 supports interface [covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx) which allows downconverting read-only generic interfaces into the same interface with a base class, so it may or may not be helpful in your situation... that is, if you weren't stuck with 3.5:

```
IEnumerable<Bob> myList = new BindingList<SubBob>();
```

Comment: I applaud at how you put it all in three small paragraphs.

Answer (score 1):

If you're stuck with .NET 3.5 and cannot change your data access layer to provide something more convenient, you can use a rather **dirty** conversion:

```
BindingList<SubBob> subBobs = new BindingList<SubBob>;
BindingList<Bob> bobs = new BindingList(subBobs.Cast<Bob>().ToList())
```

Apart from mediocre design, this introduces the cost of reconstructing the list from `IEnumerable<>` in `ToList()`. `BindingList<>` constructor on the other hand only wraps the list.